# T-SQL/SSRS - Displaying value when no rows can are available to count

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services

I'm using a SSRS tablix to sort data in to hour ranges (over a 24hour period) however, if there are no rows within that hour the tablix will not display that row/group.

Any suggestions, I've tried CASE, iif's, even using text boxes as place holders and short of using indervidual tablix for each hour and simply changing the no data message to be '0' I'm out of ideas.

Comment: can you post your data source ?

Comment: **SELECT** 
date and time, 
kind, 
id,
equipment 
**FROM** 
area
**WHERE** 
date and time > dateadd(hh, 7, cast(@DateSet as smalldatetime))
**AND**
date and time < dateadd(hh, 31, cast(@DateSet as smalldatetime));

Comment: well you should calculate an hour column and select from HourTable left join your query. HourTable should be `select 0 union select 1 ... union select 23`(creation an "hours dimension" table sounds like a good idea). In this way you will have one row even for empty hours.

Comment: I cannot create/drop/modify tables as they are live/global standard! I need to get it to work within the report software essentially, its one of the many problems I face with the DB/s we work with! :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try the following pattern:

```
select
    * -- better naming columns
from
    (
        select 0 as [hour]
        union select 1
        union select 2
        union select 3
        union select 4
        union select 5
        union select 6
        union select 7
        union select 8
        union select 9
        union select 10
        union select 11
        union select 12
        union select 13
        union select 14
        union select 15
        union select 16
        union select 17
        union select 18
        union select 19
        union select 20
        union select 21
        union select 22
        union select 23
    ) dimHour
    left join (
        -- you query here cointaining an hour column
    ) facts on dimHour.[hour] = facts.[hour]
```

This way you will have at least a row for each hour of the day.

Comment: this is not a modification of the db, just a way to write the datasource.